# JPA onetoone relationship target gets insert instead of update

Tags: java, mysql, jpa

**i have already seen the similar questions and havent been able to figure it out from them**

i have two beans they have a unidirectional onetoone relationship.

the table below contains a forigen key to Requestattachment

```
public class Requesttracking implements Serializable {
@OneToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, cascade=CascadeType.PERSIST)
@JoinColumn(name="raid")
private Requestattachment requestattachment;
```

this it the table i use to store the attachments

```
public class Requestattachment implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int raid;

@Lob
private byte[] attachment;
```

now to add a new entity i can just add Requesttracking.set(requestattachment) and persist it and it works perfectly.

my problem is when i try to update requestracking.

```
Requesttracking r=em.find(Requesttracking.class, rt.getRqid());
r.setRequestattachment(rt.getRequestattachment());
em.flush();
```

instead of updating the requestattachment, what this does is creates a new requestattachement adds it to the requestattachment table and adds the new forigen key to requesttracking table.

The problem with this i have is that now there is just an entry in requestattachment sitting which has no meaning.

What i would like to happen is that requestattachment retains the same primary key just updates the attachment hence the foreign key in requesttracking remains unchanged.

i have thought of a couple of ways i could solve this, just delete the old requestattachment when i update. or update requestattachment manually and leave it as is in request tracking. but i feel like there realy should be a better way and i am missing something

Comment: and "rt.getRequestAttachment" is in what state ? transient? detached? managed?

Comment: Are you sure that rt.getRequestattachment() returns a managed instance?

Comment: @NeilStockton  it is in detached state

Comment: then perhaps look in the log of whichever JPA implementation you use and see what it says for that operation. I know the impl I use would say what is happening